# How to not lose format of html template converted as pdf in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
const pdf = require('html-pdf')
const path = require('path')
const pdfTemplate = require('../documents/gatepassDocu');

exports.createPdf = (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { description, destination, dateOfTravel, serviceVehicle, department, employeeName } = req.body;
  
      // Generate the HTML content using your template and data
      const htmlContent = pdfTemplate({
        description,
        destination,
        dateOfTravel,
        serviceVehicle,
        department,
        employeeName,
      });
  
      // to save the PDF file
      const pdfFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'gatepass.pdf');
  
      // Generate PDF from HTML content and save it
      pdf.create(htmlContent, { format: 'Letter', orientation: 'landscape'}).toFile(pdfFilePath, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
          return res.status(500).send('PDF Generation Failed');
        }
        
        // Send the generated PDF file as a response
        res.sendFile(pdfFilePath);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send('PDF Generation Error');
    }
  };


  exports.fetchPdf = (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'gatepass.pdf');
    res.sendFile(filePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error sending PDF:', err);
            res.status(500).send('PDF Sending Error');
        }
    });
  };
```

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/Gatepass.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
import { generatePdf } from './GatepassPDF';


function GeneratedGatePass(props) {

  const handleForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      // Generate the PDF data URI
      const pdfData = generatePdf({
        description: props.description,
        destination: props.destination,
        dateOfTravel: props.dateOfTravel,
        serviceVehicle: props.serviceVehicle,
        department: props.department,
        employeeName: props.employeeName,
      });
      
  
      // Send the PDF data URI to the server
      const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3001/createPdf`, pdfData);
      console.log('PDF creation response:', response.data); // Log the response for debugging
  
      // Then make the request to fetch and download the PDF
      const pdfResponse = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/fetchPdf`, { responseType: 'blob' });
      const pdfBlob = new Blob([pdfResponse.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      saveAs(pdfBlob, 'Gatepass.pdf');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Axios Error:', error);
    }
  };
  
  
  

  return (props.trigger) ? (
    <div className='popup-gate-pass'>
        <div className='gate-pass-inner'>
        <button className='close-button' onClick={() => { props.setTrigger(false); }}>
        Close
        </button>
            {props.children}
            
        </div>
        <button className='print-gatepass-button'onClick={handleForm}>Download Gatepass</button>
    </div>
  ):  '';
}

export default GeneratedGatePass;
```

and this is how I apply the html code as the template(code below).

```
module.exports = ({ description, destination, dateOfTravel, serviceVehicle, department, employeeName }) => {
    return `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title>Gate Pass</title>
          <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            text-indent: 0;
        }

        hr {
            color: #ccc;
            width: 90%;
        }

        h2 {
            color: black;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 15.5pt;
        }

        .s1 {
            color: black;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 15.5pt;
        }

        h1 {
            color: black;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18pt;
        }

        p {
            color: black;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 12pt;
            margin: 0pt;
        }

        h3 {
            color: black;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 12pt;
        }

        body {
            padding: 20px;
        }
        .pdf-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .left-side-pass,
        .right-side-pass {
            margin: 5px;
        }

        .document-header {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 15vh 1fr;
            
            text-align: left;
        }

        .document-content,
        .content-below {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            
        }

        .logo {
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .title {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .content-right {
            position: relative;
        }
        .signature-block {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 20;
        }
    </style>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div class="pdf-container">
    <div class="left-side-pass">
            <div class="document-header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td><img width="39" height="60"
                                    src="data:image/" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="header-content">
                    <h2>COMPANY NAME, INC</h2>
                    <p class="s1" >Place, Somewhere</p>
                </div>
            </div>

       <div class="document-body">
        <br>
        <div class="title">
            <h1>EMPLOYEE GATEPASS</h1>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>TO: GUARD ON DUTY</p>
        <p>Permission to leave Coop
        Headquarters is hereby granted to the following employee:</p>
       <br>
       <div class="document-content">
        <div class="content-left">
            <p>Name of Employee/s:</p>
            <h3> ${employeeName}</h3>
            <br>
            <p>Area Office:</p>
            
            <p>Department: ${department}</p> 
            <p>Time of Travel:</p>
            <p>Destination: ${destination}</p>
            <p>Purpose: ${description}</p>
            <br>
            <p>Prepared by:</p>
            <br>
            <h3>Employee</h3>
           </div>
           <div class="content-right">
            <p> Date of Travel: ${dateOfTravel}</p>
            <p>Service Vehicle: ${serviceVehicle}</p>
            <br>
            <div class="signature-block">
                <h3>Approved by:</h3>
                <p>JOHN DOE</p>
                <h3>Manager</h3>
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <h3>FOR SECURITY DIVISION</h3>
        <div class="content-below">
            <div class="content-left">
                    <p>Time out: </p>
                    <p>Checked by: </p>
                    <h3>TRAVEL VERIFICATION</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="content-right">
                <p>Time in:</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>Person/s Visited:</p>
                <p>Date and Time:</p>
                <p>Signature</p>
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side-pass">
        <div class="document-header">
            <div class="logo">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img width="39" height="60"
                                src="data:image/" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="header-content">
                <h2>COMPANY NAME, INC</h2>
                <p class="s1" >Place, Somewhere</p>
            </div>
        </div>

   <div class="document-body">
    <br>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>EMPLOYEE GATEPASS</h1>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p>TO: GUARD ON DUTY</p>
    <p>Permission to leave Coop
    Headquarters is hereby granted to the following employee:</p>
   <br>
   <div class="document-content">
    <div class="content-left">
        <p>Name of Employee/s:</p>
        <h3> ${employeeName}</h3>
        <br>
        <p>Area Office:</p>
        
        <p>Department: ${department}</p> 
        <p>Time of Travel:</p>
        <p>Destination: ${destination}</p>
        <p>Purpose: ${description}</p>
        <br>
        <p>Prepared by:</p>
        <br>
        <h3>Employee</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="content-right">
        <p> Date of Travel: ${dateOfTravel}</p>
        <p>Service Vehicle: ${serviceVehicle}</p>
        <br>
        <div class="signature-block">
            <h3>Approved by:</h3>
            <p>JOHN DOE</p>
            <h3>Manager</h3>
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <h3>FOR SECURITY DIVISION</h3>
    <div class="content-below">
        <div class="content-left">
                <p>Time out: </p>
                <p>Checked by: </p>
                <h3>TRAVEL VERIFICATION</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="content-right">
            <p>Time in:</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Person/s Visited:</p>
            <p>Date and Time:</p>
            <p>Signature</p>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   </div>
      </body>
      </html>
    `;
  };
```

This is what it looks like in my design in html:
[image]

and is fine when applied as pdf for any sizes and orientation.

And this is what resulted as generated pdf:
[image]

I have to say that it's just a month since I'm doing ReactJS I've used chatgpt in some of my codes because it has become my way to easily learn the code structure and algorithm execution. I'm lost on this part so I hope that someone will help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: yep, that's what I am confused about, it is fine when applied to a pdf but the result is just overlapping content and it results as a page for each instead of a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading a bunch of articles and conversations with chatgpt, I've figured out that my problem is the pdf generation library that I'm using which is the html-pdf, it does not support the other css styles that I've used in my html template that's why I've lost the format. So I've resolved this by changing the library.

This is how I've implemented using the puppeteer library.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');

exports.createPdf = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { description, destination, dateOfTravel, serviceVehicle, department, employeeName } = req.body;

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

    // Create a new page
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Generate the HTML content using your template and data
    const htmlContent = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Gate Pass</title>
        <style>
      * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          text-indent: 0;
      }

      hr {
          color: #ccc;
          width: 90%;
      }

      h2 {
          color: black;
          font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 15.5pt;
      }

      .s1 {
          color: black;
          font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: normal;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 15.5pt;
      }

      h1 {
          color: black;
          font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 18pt;
      }

      p {
          color: black;
          font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: normal;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 12pt;
          margin: 0pt;
      }

      h3 {
          color: black;
          font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: bold;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 12pt;
      }

      body {
          padding: 20px;
      }
      .pdf-container {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
          padding: 10px;
      }

      .left-side-pass,
      .right-side-pass {
          margin: 5px;
      }

      .document-header {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 15vh 1fr;
          
          text-align: left;
      }

      .document-content,
      .content-below {
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
          
      }

      .logo {
          margin-left: 20px;
      }

      .title {
          text-align: center;
      }

      .content-right {
          position: relative;
      }
      .signature-block {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 20;
      }
      
  </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="pdf-container">
  <div class="left-side-pass">
          <div class="document-header">
              <div class="logo">
                  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                          <td><img width="39" height="60"
                                  src="data:image/" />
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div class="header-content">
                  <h2>COMPANY NAME, INC</h2>
                  <p class="s1" >Place, Somewhere</p>
              </div>
          </div>

     <div class="document-body">
      <br>
      <div class="title">
          <h1>EMPLOYEE GATEPASS</h1>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>TO: GUARD ON DUTY</p>
      <p>Permission to leave Coop
      Headquarters is hereby granted to the following employee:</p>
     <br>
     <div class="document-content">
      <div class="content-left">
          <p>Name of Employee/s:</p>
          <h3> ${employeeName}</h3>
          <br>
          <p>Area Office:</p>
          
          <p>Department: ${department}</p> 
          <p>Time of Travel:</p>
          <p>Destination: ${destination}</p>
          <p>Purpose: ${description}</p>
          <br>
          <p>Prepared by:</p>
          <br>
          <h3>Employee</h3>
         </div>
         <div class="content-right">
          <p> Date of Travel: ${dateOfTravel}</p>
          <p>Service Vehicle: ${serviceVehicle}</p>
          <br>
          <div class="signature-block">
              <h3>Approved by:</h3>
              <p>JOHN DOE</p>
              <h3>Manager</h3>
          </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <br>
      <hr>
      <br>
      <h3>FOR SECURITY DIVISION</h3>
      <div class="content-below">
          <div class="content-left">
                  <p>Time out: </p>
                  <p>Checked by: </p>
                  <h3>TRAVEL VERIFICATION</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="content-right">
              <p>Time in:</p>
          </div>
          <div>
              <p>Person/s Visited:</p>
              <p>Date and Time:</p>
              <p>Signature</p>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side-pass">
      <div class="document-header">
          <div class="logo">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                      <td><img width="39" height="60"
                              src="data:image/" />
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </div>
          <div class="header-content">
              <h2>COMPANY NAME, INC</h2>
              <p class="s1" >Place, Somewhere</p>
          </div>
      </div>

 <div class="document-body">
  <br>
  <div class="title">
      <h1>EMPLOYEE GATEPASS</h1>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p>TO: GUARD ON DUTY</p>
  <p>Permission to leave Coop
  Headquarters is hereby granted to the following employee:</p>
 <br>
 <div class="document-content">
  <div class="content-left">
      <p>Name of Employee/s:</p>
      <h3> ${employeeName}</h3>
      <br>
      <p>Area Office:</p>
      
      <p>Department: ${department}</p> 
      <p>Time of Travel:</p>
      <p>Destination: ${destination}</p>
      <p>Purpose: ${description}</p>
      <br>
      <p>Prepared by:</p>
      <br>
      <h3>Employee</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="content-right">
      <p> Date of Travel: ${dateOfTravel}</p>
      <p>Service Vehicle: ${serviceVehicle}</p>
      <br>
      <div class="signature-block">
          <h3>Approved by:</h3>
          <p>JOHN DOE</p>
          <h3>Manager</h3>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <br>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <h3>FOR SECURITY DIVISION</h3>
  <div class="content-below">
      <div class="content-left">
              <p>Time out: </p>
              <p>Checked by: </p>
              <h3>TRAVEL VERIFICATION</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="content-right">
          <p>Time in:</p>
      </div>
      <div>
          <p>Person/s Visited:</p>
          <p>Date and Time:</p>
          <p>Signature</p>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="invoice-box">

  </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    `;

    // Set the content of the page
    await page.setContent(htmlContent);

    // Specify the PDF options
    const pdfOptions = {
      path: path.join(__dirname, 'gatepass.pdf'),
      format: 'Letter',
      landscape: true,
    };

    // Generate the PDF
    await page.pdf(pdfOptions);

    // Close the browser
    await browser.close();

    // Send the generated PDF file as a response
    res.sendFile(pdfOptions.path);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('PDF Generation Error');
  }
};

exports.fetchPdf = (req, res) => {
  const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'gatepass.pdf');
  res.sendFile(filePath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error sending PDF:', err);
      res.status(500).send('PDF Sending Error');
    }
  });
};
```